# Integrated Graphics not recognized on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.04

I've got an Asus G751JW which has an Nvidia GTX 970M and some integrated intel graphics card as far as I know. What I'd like to do is disable the Nvidia card and just use the integrated graphics.

Mostly because I don't game on the system anyway, but also because the proprietary nvidia drivers do not work properly. I get graphics errors constantly which mess up the login screen so I cannot log in anymore at times. Also I can't change the display's brightness no matter which driver I use for the Nvidia card (and I have tried lots of things to fix this to no avail) ...

Anyway, so I heard you can switch to intel using `prime-select`. Nope. I can't since the intel card is not recognized.

I also heard you can disable the Nvidia card using `bbswitch`. Nope, cause the intel card is not recognized.

Any idea why the integrated card is not recognized?

[image: additional drivers]

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 22da
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: I see you only have version 346 installed - maybe installing a later version would fix things?

Comment: You can see that even 346 is not installed.

Comment: As I said I did try it though and it didn't work very well. The xorg variant at least doesn't bug out on me on the login screen.

Comment: And where is the Intel adapter in `lspci`? Check bios if it is enabled.

Comment: You know, you have a good point there. My BIOS is very simple. Couldn't find any options to enable or disable integrated graphics. Now I'm not even sure anymore if the laptop does have it ... I just figured as much seeing as the 'additional drivers' showed the lower section with the intel micro code stuff just as with my other laptop which just has an integrated intel card.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Nvidia proprietary drivers to use nvidia-prime.
Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

You will be able no switch adapters in Nvidia X Server Settings and by `prime-select` command.

If the 346 driver does not work well, you can install 352 by

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo killall nvidia-persistenced
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Comment: 355 is a later version - is it still dev?

Comment: It is beta. Stable is 352.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately doing this somehow *removed* nvidia-prime. `apt-get` says it's already installed. Can't find the binary though.

Running `/usr/bin/nvidia-settings` starts the Nvidia settings and shows the following output on the console:

   `** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort`
   `** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no`

Comment: Also the driver behaves just like the old one unfortunately. Weird graphics erros on login screen (it's like it's half terminal half X) and the brightness still cannot be changed. :(

Comment: Switch to Intel if you like.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I added a command. Please try again. The driver could not install.

Comment: I've added the output to the question. Unfortunately I cannot switch to intel as `nvidia-prime` seems to be gone as I said. And even when I still had it with 346 it just failed to select intel as the only other device was 'unknown'.

Comment: As for the additional command: I've installed the driver on the root shell through recovery mode. Do you think that makes a difference? I.e. should I still try again or is the `killall nvidia-persistenced` absolutely necessary even when x is not running?

Comment: Regarding the first command: `E: Invalid operation purge-nvidia*`

Comment: Fixed the command. Were there any errors when you installed the driver?

Comment: Nope, didn't see any errors.